# How to programatically change image style of images gathered by view?

Tags: views, 8

I have a view that collect fields of some content type and one of those fields is image field. I can set image style for that image from view editing page and that image in every row will have that same image style.

Now I need to set different image style for some rows. I.e. first row image should have style "ep1", second "ep2" and third and fourth "ep3".

What I tried so far is pre-processing image field like this:

```
function hook_preprocess_views_view_field(&$variables)
{
  $view = $variables['view'];
  $field = $variables['field'];


  switch ($view->id()){
    case 'view_id':
      switch($field->field) {
        case 'image_id':
          $rowIndex = $variables["field"]->view->row_index;

          $variables['field']->options["settings"]["image_style"] = 'thumbnail';
          break;
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

This way I can collect row number, but setting this "thumbnail" style is not working. On front-end I'm still getting image style set from view.

Then I tried preprocessing image formatter like this:

```
function cr_common_preprocess_image_formatter(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['image']['#style_name'] === 'style_to_change') {
    $variables['image']['#style_name'] = 'thumbnail';
  }
}
```

And this way style really is changed, but I don't' have info on current view row so it can be used only for setting random image styles or something.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a different approach, via the Views UI, adding the same image field 3 times, and assigning each of these different image styles.

Add a `View result counter` field, this will let you know the row number.

Then on template/twig file print image field that was assigned x image if `counter` <sub>(this is the twig variable name for View result counter)</sub> equals y.

Comment: Not exactly but I was looking for, but useful.